# How to check a php response for string with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax query sending to a php script and putting the response into a div. The code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "core/process.php",
data: data,
success: function(response){
   $("#form").fadeOut('slow');
   alert("DO NOT LEAVE THIS PAGE UNTIL COMPLETE");
   $("#response").html("DO NOT LEAVE THIS PAGE UNTIL COMPLETE<br />")
   .append(response)
   .hide()
   .slideDown('slow');
}
});
```

What I want to do is check the response for a string or return such as "true" or "success" or whatever and alert the user the script is complete. I know very little jQuery beyond what you see above and am not sure how to search a response for something specific.

**Edit:** I just realized I forgot to put how the script outputs the response. It's just echoing in the php script. I'm thinking I may need to put everything into an array and json_encode it, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) function:

```
if (response.indexOf('success') > -1 || response.indexOf('true') > -1) {
    // the response contains one or both of the strings success and true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/Success/.test(response)) {
  alert('Cool')
}
```

Or change the response type to json and have the server encode a status code and output string as the result object.